# C#: read text file separated by additional newline character

Tags: c#, file-io

I have some sql commands that are separated by an additional newline character:

```
ALTER TABLE XXX
ALTER COLUMN xxx real

ALTER TABLE YYY
ALTER COLUMN yyy real

ALTER TABLE ZZZ
ALTER COLUMN zzz real
```

I've tried reading the file by using an array of character separators such as the following,

`new char[] { '\n', '\r'}`

inside this method:

```
    private static List<string> ReadFile(string FileName, char[] seps)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File not found");
            return null;
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.Default))
        {
            string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return content.Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. I would like to have each command represented by a separate string. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd just use `ReadAllLines` and then the empty lines will be your chunk separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers. I ended up going with this helper method:

```
    private static List<string> GetCommands(string location)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        List<string> tmp = ReadFile(location, new string[] { "\r\n\r\n"});

        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
        {
            string rem = tmp[i].Replace("\r", "");
            ret.Add(rem);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

As an aside, the equivalent is so much easier in Python. For example, what I'm trying to do can be expressed in these three lines:

```
with open('commands.txt', 'r') as f:
    content  = f.read()
    commands = [ command for command in content.split('\n\n') ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `File.ReadAllLines()`?

```
private static List<string> ReadFile(string FileName)
{
    if (!File.Exists(FileName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File not found");
        return null;
    }

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
    return lines.ToList();
}
```

This will automatically read and split your file by newlines.

If you want to filter out empty lines, do this:

```
var nonEmpty = ReadFile(path).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
```

---

Side note, I would change your if statement to throw an exception if the file cannot be found.

```
if (!File.Exists(FileName))
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't find file");
}
```

Comment: this is good but I'd like the SQL statements together. For example, this won't yield "ALTER TABLE XXX\nALTER COLUMN xxx real":

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the examples.  When I read them in, the empty lines had a length 1 and its char value said 131 for some reason.  So I just filtered by length > 1

```
void Main()
```

{
    var results = ReadFile(@"C:\temp\sql.txt", new char[]{'\n'});
    Console.WriteLine(results.Count);
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

```
private static List<string> ReadFile(string FileName, char[] seps)
{
    if (!File.Exists(FileName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File not found");
        return null;
    }

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.Default))
    {
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return content.Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where (c => c.Length > 1).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
private static List<string> ReadFile(string FileName)
  {
      List<string> commands = new List<string>();
      StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();

      if (!File.Exists(FileName))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("File not found");
          return null;
      }

      foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(FileName))
      {
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
          {
              command.Append(line + "\n");
          }
          else
          {
              commands.Add(command.ToString());
              command.Clear();
          }
      }
      commands.Add(command.ToString());
      return commands;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you'll always have \r\n line endings, you can use:

```
var commands = content.Split(new []{"\r\n\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Otherwise, try using regex:

```
var commands = Regex.Split(content, @"\r?\n\r?\n")
```